# How to call JS function in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

My problem is that i want to call a js function on a TextBox attribute "OnTextChanged", the js function should check if the text in TextBox is correct and set visibility of Button.

Here is my asp code:

```
...
<head runat="server">
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("Verify.js") %>"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="FirstTextBox" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" Text="Add person" Height="23px" OnClick="AddButton_Click"/>
...
</form>
</body>
```

js(in another file):

```
function Valid()
{
    var textBox = '<%= FirstTextBox.ClientID %>';
    var acceptButton = '<%= AddButton.ClientID %>';
    var text= document.getElementById(textBox).value;
    var accept = document.getElementById(acceptButton);
    if(data correct)
    {
        do things..
    }
    else
    {
        accept.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

and in c# code i set attribute for TextBox.

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude("Verify", "Verify.js");
this.FirstTextBox.Attributes.Add("OnTextChanged", "Valid()");
```

JS function isn't execute, it looks like the program even didn't go inside the js funcion. Anyone have an idea what i doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: What do you mean "what am i doing wrong"? You haven't told us *what* is going wrong to begin with.

Comment: The js variables `'<%= FirstTextBox.ClientID %>'` and `'<%= AddButton.ClientID %>'` are not going to be evaluated by .net - that js file will be served literally. I would think you are getting console errors `cannot read property 'value' of null`?

Comment: I think you should use `onChange` js event instead server `OnTextChanged`

Comment: @DaveParsons i don't get any errors at the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two issues here:

1. There isn't a javascript event `OnTextChanged` this should be updated to `onchange` or `onkeypress` depending on the responsiveness you are looking for.
2. Your external javascript value contains code blocks which will not be evaluated, as powerful as .NET
   can be it's not going to randomly parse your resources for code blocks and attempt to make sense of them
   in the current context.

Given your current set up I think the easiest way is to update your code as follows:

JS:

```
function Valid(textboxId, btnId){
    var textBox = textboxId;
    var acceptButton = btnId;
    var text= document.getElementById(textBox).value;
    var accept = document.getElementById(acceptButton);
    if(data correct)
    {
        do things..
    }
    else
    {
        accept.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

C#:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude("Verify", "Verify.js");
this.FirstTextBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", string.Format("Valid('{0}', '{1}')",FirstTextBox.ClientID, AddButton.ClientID));
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use onchange instead of OnTextChanged which is Server Side event.